# How to make Jq return always in array

Tags: bash, jq, xq

My input may be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>UserTriggerHandler_Test</members>
        <members>UserTriggerHandasdler_Test</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>UserTriggerHandasdler_Test</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Xp value for these are :

```
{
    "Package": {
        "@xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",
        "types": {
            "members": "UserTriggerHandasdler_Test",
            "name": "ApexClass"
        },
        "version": "52.0"
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "Package": {
        "@xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",
        "types": {
            "members": ["UserTriggerHandler_Test", "UserTriggerHandasdler_Test"],
            "name": "ApexClass"
        },
        "version": "52.0"
    }
}
```

Respectively.

And I am trying to pass the input to this function.

```
classsvalue=`cat manifest/package.xml | xq . | jq '.Package.types | if type=="array" then .[] else . end | select(.name=="ApexClass") |select(.members!="Test")|.members | join(",")'`
echo $classsvalue
```

But it fails because of `join(",")`. I want to force `jq` to always return members in an array. Is this possible?

I am expecting out put as `"UserTriggerHandasdler_Test"` and `"UserTriggerHandasdler_Test,UserTriggerHandasdler_Test"` respectively.

Comment: `value=$(anything)` or its backtick-based equivalent will _never_ be an array. As always, populating an array requires using `readarray`, `mapfile`, `read -a`, etc.

Comment: BTW, could you provide the `xq` output in the question itself so folks don't need to have it on hand to test their answers? This question is currently only tagged `bash` and `jq`; `xq` is not included with either bash or jq (indeed, I've never heard of it).

Comment: Added the `xq` output too.

Comment: Okay. And can you be clear about what you mean by "as an array"? Do you mean a string with a JSON array, or a bash array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't really an array, so I'm ignoring that part of the question.

```
# Original, unmodified code here
.Package.types |
if type=="array" then .[] else . end |
select(.name=="ApexClass") |
select(.members!="Test") |
.members |
# New code here
if type == "string" then [.] else . end | join(",")
```

That last line is the critical part -- wrapping the result in a list, should it be a string, before doing the `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ bundled version of xq using `pip install yq` then you have some additional options available:

```
$ xq --help

  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --xml-output, -x      Transcode jq JSON output back into XML and emit it
  --xml-item-depth XML_ITEM_DEPTH
                        Specify depth of items to emit (default 0; use a positive integer to stream large docs)
  --xml-dtd             Preserve XML Document Type Definition (disables streaming of multiple docs)
  --xml-root XML_ROOT   When transcoding back to XML, envelope the output in an element with this name
  --xml-force-list XML_FORCE_LIST
                        Emit a list for elements with this name even if they occur only once (option can repeat)
  --in-place, -i        Edit files in place (no backup - use caution)
  --version             show program's version number and exit
```

`--xml-force-list` Emit a list for elements with this name even if they occur only once (option can repeat)

Therefore should be able to do:

```
cat manifest/package.xml | xq . --xml-force-list "members"
```

Which will ensure `members` is always an array whether there is one instance or more than one.

This uses the https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict library `force_list` function.